# Creating VBA Function

Tags: vba, excel

I really need some assistance with creating this function for a VBA project. I am not sure what I am doing wrong here. I am trying to create a function, however, I keep getting an error message of Function not valid. I have been searching what may be wrong but I cannot find out where my error may be at.

```
Function Duplicate(FirstCell) As Object

Dim SecondCell
Dim ThirdCell
Dim FourthCell

SecondCell = ActiveCell.Offset(1, 1).Select
ThirdCell = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Select
FourthCell = ActiveCell.Offset(1, 2).Select


If FirstCell = SecondCell And ThirdCell = FourthCell Then
   Duplicate = "Dup"
Else
   Duplicate = ""

End If
End Function
```

Comment: maybe you'll tell what what you are trying to achieve ?? In anyway, if your function is returning an `Object`, then either `Set Duplicate = ...` , or declare your function as `String` or `Variant`

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the feedback. What I am trying to get this to do is print out Dup if FirstCell is equal to SecondCell and print out nothing ThirdCell is equal to FourthCell. I have declared my function both as a String and Variant and that does not seem to have worked. The SecondCell, ThirdCell, and FourthCell should be reference from the current active cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How's this?

```
Function Duplicate(byVal FirstCell as Range) As String

Dim SecondCell as Range, ThirdCell as Range, FourthCell as Range

Set SecondCell = FirstCell.Offset(1, 1)
Set ThirdCell = FirstCell.Offset(0, 2)
Set FourthCell = FirstCell.Offset(1, 2)


If FirstCell.Value = SecondCell.Value And ThirdCell.Value = FourthCell.Value Then
   Duplicate = "Dup"
Else
   Duplicate = ""

End If
End Function
```

Use this like `=Duplicate(A1)`.

The thing I'm not sure on needs clarification: What do you want to return if `FirstCell = SecondCell` **and** `ThirdCell = FourthCell`? Or, no matter what, if `ThirdCell = FourthCell` do you want to return nothing?

Comment: Hey thanks for the help. I just want to make a condition to return "Dup" only if `FirstCell = SecondCell` **and** `ThirdCell = FourthCell`. If they do not meet those conditions then I want to return nothing even if  `ThirdCell = FourthCell`. Also FirstCell, SecondCell, ThirdCell, and FourthCell will all be strings.

Comment: Thank you! It did work. I really appreciate your help.